# Installshield desktop shortcut icon shows windows default icon

Tags: installshield

I have inherited an installscript project which asks the user if they want a desktop shortcut.  The script creates the shortcut, but Windows gives it a default icon rather than the icon specified.  When you look at the properties of the shortcut, the correct icon is displayed.

I see on [this page](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield18helplib/mergedProjects/installshield18langref/LangrefAddFolderIcon.htm) the following:
"The shortcut target must be present on the target system before AddFolderIcon can be called."  And I'm wondering if that's the cause of the issue.

The installscript is creating shortcuts in the `OnFirstUIBefore()` function.  Do we need to instead create these shortcuts in the `OnFirstUIAfter()` function, after the executable has been copied to the user's machine?  And if so, do we need to delay that dialog which asks them if they want the shortcut, or is there a way to save those answers until we get to that function?

I don't recall seeing an install which copies files and then asks you more questions about shortcuts.

We are using Installshield 2012 Spring if that is relevant at all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

FWIW I gave up and decided to create the shortcuts using the installation designer.  Now they function correctly; however the install dialogs no longer ask the user if they want the shortcuts.